Christmas movie about a group of young teens.
I watched this movie a few years ago (perhaps 3-4 years ago). I don't remember the actors in it. I watched it on Television. Real time and colour movie. 
Details I remember about the film
It is a movie set at the time of Christmas. It has a group of young teens. The characters team up as a group but they are not groups since the beginning. The main character is a Caucasian boy. The group consists of the main character, a girl he likes, his little sister, African American nerdy boy and a girl who likes him in the end. I guess this nerdy boy has done in other movies too. He was the only one I remembered when I watched the movie from other movies. (I don't remember the name of the boy pr the films he previously acted). 
The group is lost (or waiting for a connecting flight. I don't remember properly) and was stuck at an airport. There is a male employee assists the main character at the air port. The airport management is very strict about celebrating Christmas. The main character asks why they are not celebrating, The employee says the staff wants to celebrate but don't celebrate due to their manager's pressure. There is a dialogue by the employee.

Employee: The manager agreed to put two ribbons. The red one is for Santa Claus and green one represents Christmas tree. 

The main character then decides to bring Christmas spirit in the airport. With the help of others, he succeeds in doing that. Comedy is also involved in the film. 
Other details:
Country of Origin: American 
Time of release: 2000's movie. 
Language : English 

I think this is Unaccompanied Minors (2006)

A group of unaccompanied minors bond while snowed in at the midwestern Hoover International Airport during the holiday season and ultimately create a makeshift holiday themselves.




There is dialogue similar to that you quoted...

Well, our boss doesn't really like Christmas so he locked all the decorations away.
But he did let us put up a few things.
For example, you see that over there?
That green thing is a Christmas tree, and those red thingies are holly.

Read more: Wikipedia
